# How to turn of telnet and FTP on Thomson 789vn router?

Tags: ports, routing

I have run a [port scan](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5897) against a Thomson 789vn router and have noticed to my surprise that its HTTP as well as telnet and FTP ports are open.

How can one turn off telnet (also FTP) using the router's management interface? Is there a good reason that speaks against doing that?

The product is by now several years old and I have not found the required information in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to telnet onto it? I had a similar Thomson router which if you telnet onto has it's own command line interface. It wasn't very intuitve, but once you get the hang of it you can figure out how to remove services.

Comment: Yep, the problem is fixed in the meantime (but I forgot to mention it here.) The telnet and FTP account (and password) coincide with those for HTTP access. When the firewall mode is on telnet and FTP can still be accessed from inside, but not from outside my subnet, which is good enough for my current purposes.